# How can I merge two adjacent DIVs into one?

Tags: javascript, html

HTML DOM

```
<div class="box-1">
...
</div>
<div class="box-2">
...
</div>
```

Can I use JavaScript to delete this part of `</div><div class="box-2">`?

Any help, thanks in advance!

Comment: If you have a container element, you should get its innerHTML, then use regex to remove the `</div><div class="box-2">` part. And then set the resulting string as the container's innerHTML

Comment: What Teemu refers to with "No"  is, that you need to start from the parent element and delete a certain child element with `remove()`.

Comment: @Akshay Simply moving all children from `.box-2` to `.box-1` would keep event handlers intact, whereas `innerHTML` modifications would not.

Comment: You mean this `</div><div class="box-2">` is a "_DOM element_"?

Comment: You seem to be thinking of the page content as _text_, which it is not. Once the browser has processed the page source these are DOM elements (Document Object Model), which you can manipulate, but not by rewriting the original text. `ibrahim`'s answer seems to be what **I** think you're trying to accomplish, but the question could use some clarifying. What is the _goal_ of deleting the part you describe? Is the goal combining two divs into a single div?

Comment: @StephenP Sorry, I didn't use the correct question title. As you said, I would like to combine the two DIVs into one.

Comment: @Yoshi, yes that would be the better option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using DOM methods, a simplified example could be:

```js
// ref .box-1 and .box-2
const box1 = document.querySelector('.box-1');
const box2 = document.querySelector('.box-2');

// move all child nodes from box2 to box1
// Array.from (or any method to copy a *live* DOM NodeList) is needed,
// for otherwise the DOM manipulation would throw off the loop 
Array.from(box2.childNodes).forEach(child => box1.appendChild(child));

// afterwards, remove box2
box2.parentNode.removeChild(box2);
```

```html
<div class="box-1">
    <span>A</span>
    B
</div>

<div class="box-2">
    <span>C</span>
    D
</div>
```

---

Another option would be to use string manipulation on some element's `innerHTML`, but that get's messy fast, so I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong you want to add the children of the next sibling into the previous one and get rid of the former. In that case consider this input:

```
<div class="box-1">
    SomeText 
    <div>child</div>
</div>
<div class="box-2">
    Some other text 
    <div>other child</div>
</div>
```

You can write this function or something of sort:

```
function transfer(node){
    var next = node.nextElementSibling;
    if(!next){return};
    while(next.hasChildNodes()){
        node.appendChild(next.firstChild)
    }
    next.parentNode.removeChild(next);
}

transfer(body.querySelector("div"));
```

You would get:

```
<div class="box-1">
    SomeText 
    <div>child</div>
    Some other text
    <div>other child</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's working

```
    var elmnt1 = document.getElementsByClassName("box-1")[0];
    var elmnt2 = document.getElementsByClassName("box-2")[0];
    elmnt1.appendchild(elmnt2);
    elmnt2.remove();
```

Comment: This will just nest box 2 into box 1

Comment: @Fitzi Oh thanks ! your code is True, I didn't think about contents :(

Answer (score 0):

The script moves the first occurence of a div with class="box-2" into the div with class="box-1". If you want this to work on multiple divs, you would need to do some kind of loop based on a selection with `document.querySelectorAll()`.

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick=ev=>{
 let b1=document.querySelector('.box-1');
 let b2=document.querySelector('.box-2');
 if (b1&&b2) {
   b1.innerHTML+='<br>'+b2.innerHTML; // I added a line break here ...
   b2.parentNode.removeChild(b2);
 }
}
```

```css
.box-1 {background-color: green}
.box-2 {background-color: red}
```

```html
<div class="box-1">
This is BOX 1
</div>
<div class="box-2">
This is BOX 2
</div>
<button>move 1 to 2</button>
```

Comment: I realize this is not "original" content, but it *is* a piece of code that does what the OP seems to want. Or isn't it? In that case it would be courteous to explain why, before downvoting.

Comment: My impression is that OP wants to eliminate the close-div of box-1 and the open-div of box-2, essentially turning two divs into one. Of course that can't be done that way because that's thinking of things in terms of _text_, not DOM elements, but if what I'm thinking is indeed what OP wants... that _can_ be done. (and… not the downvoter)

Comment: :D thanks for explaining! Yes the title of the post is more than misleading! :D:D He wants to **merge** two divs!

Comment: @cars10m Sorry, I didn't use the correct question title.

Answer (score 0):

Interpreting the fact that you wan't to remove `</div><div class="box-2">`, which basically "moves" the content of `box-2` into `box-1` you may do something like this:

```js
document.querySelector('#move').addEventListener('click', function(){

  let box1 = document.querySelector('.box-1');
  let box2 = document.querySelector('.box-2');
  
  // copy the dom of box 2 into box 1
  box1.innerHTML += box2.innerHTML;
  
  // remove box 2
  box2.remove();
  
});
```

```css
.box-1 {
  color: red;
}

.box-2 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-1">
  Box 1
</div>

<div class="box-2">
  Box 2

  <p>
    Test
  </p>
</div>

<button id="move">
  move content
</button>
```

Not the most elegant solution, but does the job.
Please note that this does not move the actual nodes but rather copies the content. This means that any reference you held in your js to an element inside box 2 will no longer be valid.